# How to make mobile app from file html in repository github

Tags: javascript, html, github, web, mobile

Can change a GitHub repository file for web to a mobile app ?

solution from my case please i need help from you all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repositary using git bash in your local storage. After that you can run your code get to know how things works and the same you do for mobile app same like that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).